# z-index issue only inside the wordpress gutenberg editor

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

i am adding a style variation to the group block. and it should have a nice box shadow that uses the before and after pseudo elements with a z-index.
all is working great on the front side but the z-index dowsn’t work inside the editor:

this is my css code:

```
.editor-styles-wrapper
 .wp-block-group.is-style-gutrs-box-shadow-raise-two-sides,
.wp-block-group.is-style-gutrs-box-shadow-raise-two-sides {
   position: relative;

 &:before,
 &:after {
   z-index: -1;
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   bottom: 15px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 50%;
   top: 80%;
   max-width: 300px;
   background: #777;
   box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }

 &:after {
   transform: rotate(3deg);
   right: 10px;
   left: auto;
 }
}
```

this is how it looks on the front:
[image]

but this is how it looks inside the editor:

[image]

any idea why the z-index property doesn't work inside the editor?

best regards

Comment: It is totally depend on the your Gutenberg block structure.
Can you please share the structure?

Comment: hi what do you mean by block structure? i assume code view? i cannot past it here error message too long. but it is only a group block that get the class of the style variation

Comment: also if i check inside the editor the group block with the dev tools, the before and after are there, but not showing. if i change in the dev tools the z-index to 0 instead of -1, the before and after does display, but above the group, which is obviously not what should be. i also tried making the before and after z: 0, and the group set to 10, but it still not working

Comment: I'm finding that gutenberg adds styles from the front end stylesheet into the block editor. That's great and all, except when it comes to things like z-index. I had an element that was a nested group with a z-index of -1 on it. This made it so that it wasn't visible in the editor.